# When a user registers, create a page from an existing template with their username as the page name

Tags: templates, users, automation

I am wondering if something like this is possible? If so, where would I start! I'm certainly not looking for someone to explain 100% fully and give free code examples etc, only a nudge in the right direction. :)

I've done some exhaustive Google searching and I believe I might not be searching for the right things.

Here's hoping!

All the best

Comment: Without knowing what you want to do exactly: I am not sure if this is what WordPress is made for. If you want to stick to WordPress, then I actually wouldn't create a real page for every user. Instead, maybe look into creating a template that dynamically displays the user name/data. I might be able to answer your question, but please add some more background info.

Comment: +1 for @Sven also what do you mean exactly with "existing template"?

Comment: An existing template, I meant a custom template that you can make in wordpress, on the publish area, where the drop-down template list is.

I've created one that I am trying to get the page that is auto created upon user registration to use. 

I do hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it sounds like you might be able to solve your underlying question using [BuddyPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress/).

If you simply want to make an actual WordPress page if a user registers you can do that using the `user_register` hook. The hook receives the newly created user ID.

This code example should create a page with the user's `nicename`.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_add_page_for_user' );

function myplugin_add_page_for_user( $user_id ) {

    // Get the user for this user_id
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );

    // The data for the page we are going to add
    $page_data = array(
        'post_type'  => 'page',
        'post_title' => $user->user_nicename
    );

    // Actually insert the post
    wp_insert_post( $page_data );

}
```

Comment: I think your function name doesn't match the add_action call. And I would include post_status and page_template in $page_data. Also - is user_nicename unique? Otherwise that could cause problems. Agree that BuddyPress could be a better solution.